# Не могу подключить MySql

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, я не давно сменил хостинг для сайта и у меня перестала подключатся база данных и на страницу не выводит никакой ошибки, а на предыдущем хостинге все работало. Не могу понять в чем причина.
Вот как я подключаюсь к базе:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","*тут я писал имя пользователя*","*тут пароль*");
    $db = mysql_select_db("solights_db");
    mysql_set_charset("utf8");

    if(!$connection || !$db){
        exit(mysql_error());
        echo "1";
    }
?>
```

Почему-то ошибки на экране не показывает, но как я заметил после подключения к ДБ весь код ниже не работает, работает только тот, что перед
Не уверен, что это поможет, но вот сам сайт http://solightside.com 
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, у вас сменилась версия PHP. Современные версии [не поддерживают](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php) библиотеку MySQL. Вместо неё нужно использовать библиотеки MySQLi или PDO.

Comment: Начал переводить на MySQLi, база заработала, но появились другие проблемы, но все же главная ошибка пока пропала, спасибо)